# ¿Como dejar marcada y seleccionada una opción de menú?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, md-bootstrap

A ver si me podéis echar una mano estoy haciendo una web en `bootstrap 4` con alguna ayudita de `MDB`, tengo una galería de imágenes tipo `Masonry` con menú y me gustaría que quedase marcada y seleccionada la opción **all "Todos"** al cargar la pagina.

```html
<div class="row">

      <!-- Grid column -->

      <ul class="nav flex-center flex-wrap mx-0 p-top-5 p-bottom-4 wow fadeInUp">

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="nav-link color-texto-boton filter" id="btn_modal" data-rel="all">Todos</button></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="color-texto-boton filter" data-rel="1">Reforma de Viviendas</button></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="color-texto-boton filter" data-rel="2">Sistemas de Iluminación y Led</button></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="color-texto-boton filter" data-rel="3">Instalaciones Calefaccion | AAC y Fontanería</button></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="color-texto-boton filter" data-rel="4">Sistemas de Control y Vigilancia</button></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="color-texto-boton filter" data-rel="5">Reformas Industriales</button></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="color-texto-boton filter" data-rel="6">Energía Solar y Fotovoltaica</button></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="color-texto-boton filter" data-rel="7">Instalaciones Eléctricas e Industriales</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Grid row -->

    <div class="gallery" id="gallery">

      <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2 mb-3 pics all 1 animation">
        <a href="img/jpg/proyectos/reformas/reformas-1.jpg" data-lightbox="[reformas]" title="Reformas Integrales de Vivienda"><img class="img-fluid z-depth-1 rounded" src="img/jpg/proyectos/reformas/reformas-1.jpg" alt="Reformas Integrales de Vivienda"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2 mb-3 pics all 1 animation">
        <a href="img/jpg/proyectos/reformas/reformas-2.jpg" data-lightbox="[reformas]" title="Reformas Integrales de Vivienda"><img class="img-fluid z-depth-1 rounded" src="img/jpg/proyectos/reformas/reformas-2.jpg" alt="Reformas Integrales de Vivienda"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2 mb-3 pics all 2 animation">
        <a href="img/jpg/proyectos/alumbrado/alumbrado-14.jpg" data-lightbox="[alumbrado]" title="Sistemas de Iluminación y Led"><img class="img-fluid z-depth-1 rounded" src="img/jpg/proyectos/alumbrado/alumbrado-14.jpg" alt="Sistemas de Iluminación y Led"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Lo que estas tratando de hacer es un componente navbar de bootstrap?

Comment: No, serían botones con diferentes apartados que al darle a cada uno sale una galería tipo masonry, con imágenes de la actividad en concreto. El código de los divs de la galería son muchos más, he recortado para no liar demasiado.

Comment: Usa "selected" es una propiedad de html5, pero deberás cambiar las ul,li por <Select><option> que es realmente lo que necesitas hacer.

Comment: El resto del código te funciona?. De ser así, solo sería necesario agregar la clase `active` en el primer `li`, quedando así: `<li class="nav-item active">`. [Aquí un ejemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_nav_pills_toggleable&stacked=h)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con el atributo autofocus pero en la etiqueta button no li, ya lo probe y si funciona, aqui dejo el ejemplo, solo que  al momento de ejecutar aqui no lo muestra pero en visual studio code lo probe y ya lo selecciona por default

```html
<div class="row">

      <!-- Grid column -->

      <ul class="nav flex-center flex-wrap mx-0 p-top-5 p-bottom-4 wow fadeInUp">

        <li  class="nav-item"><button autofocus type="button" class="nav-link color-texto-boton filter" id="btn_modal" data-rel="all">Todos</button></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="color-texto-boton filter" data-rel="1">Reforma de Viviendas</button></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="color-texto-boton filter" data-rel="2">Sistemas de Iluminación y Led</button></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="color-texto-boton filter" data-rel="3">Instalaciones Calefaccion | AAC y Fontanería</button></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="color-texto-boton filter" data-rel="4">Sistemas de Control y Vigilancia</button></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="color-texto-boton filter" data-rel="5">Reformas Industriales</button></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="color-texto-boton filter" data-rel="6">Energía Solar y Fotovoltaica</button></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" class="color-texto-boton filter" data-rel="7">Instalaciones Eléctricas e Industriales</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Grid row -->

    <div class="gallery" id="gallery">

      <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2 mb-3 pics all 1 animation">
        <a href="img/jpg/proyectos/reformas/reformas-1.jpg" data-lightbox="[reformas]" title="Reformas Integrales de Vivienda"><img class="img-fluid z-depth-1 rounded" src="img/jpg/proyectos/reformas/reformas-1.jpg" alt="Reformas Integrales de Vivienda"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2 mb-3 pics all 1 animation">
        <a href="img/jpg/proyectos/reformas/reformas-2.jpg" data-lightbox="[reformas]" title="Reformas Integrales de Vivienda"><img class="img-fluid z-depth-1 rounded" src="img/jpg/proyectos/reformas/reformas-2.jpg" alt="Reformas Integrales de Vivienda"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2 mb-3 pics all 2 animation">
        <a href="img/jpg/proyectos/alumbrado/alumbrado-14.jpg" data-lightbox="[alumbrado]" title="Sistemas de Iluminación y Led"><img class="img-fluid z-depth-1 rounded" src="img/jpg/proyectos/alumbrado/alumbrado-14.jpg" alt="Sistemas de Iluminación y Led"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```